# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split'); react-table v8 / Vercel preview site

Tags: vercel, react-table

I am using react-table v8. When I open my application locally, everything works fine. However, when I deploy to a Vercel preview site, I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')`. I have isolated the problem to the table body and possibly the getRowModel() or flexRender() methods. Any idea why this is happening? The data that the table is trying to render locally and on the deployed site is identical (same shape, same content).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't have the Imgix environment variable configured on my Vercel deployment... whoops.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).